# Issue with 64-bit application execution under wine (missing "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" assembly, msvcr80.dll)

Tags: wine, 64-bit, winetricks

I face the following errors when I try to run 64-bit console application with wine:

```
002a:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
002a:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.762)
002a:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x23e480, 0x23e490 0x23e484
002a:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x23e480 0x23e490 0x23e484) returning a dummy value (current locale)
002a:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0xa80000 0 0x23e7a0 4 stub
002a:err:module:attach_dlls "MSVCR80.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
002a:err:module:attach_dlls Initializing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\user\\test\\x64\\process.exe" failed, status c0000142
```

I must mention that MS Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package is already installed using command

> winetricks vcrun2005

Also I have downloaded the "msvcr80.dll" file with the exact same version (8.0.50727.762) and I have put it in the application folder.

And the issue is still not resolved unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to manually replace the library. Open the `Libraries` tab and type the library name:

```
msvcr80
```

http://prnt.sc/sbjiua

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually we solved this issue exactly this way, but unfortunately I forgot to post the answer here.